# Unregister (unsubscribe) from Push Notifications in Ionic2

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

Is there a way to unregister (unsubscribe) from Push Notifications in Ionic2?

Comment: did you manage to find get an answer for this?

Comment: @Basit I didn't really found a way to unsubscribe, but in the end I just created and used a custom database field on User in order to decide if he should receive push notifications from my system.

Comment: I have found the unsubscribe method. It actually is on cordova push notification documentation. It is very hard to find it, but it is already written from a long time.

Comment: The unsubscribe method is used when the application no longer wants to receive push notifications from a specific topic but continue to receive other push messages. Read this link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/995/commits/34b74b84cb0ac6ed50c80bdf16423d3890d70e21#diff-43f23a51712aa1ec0834bb85ea7a7812